# Normal Operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to show the following.  If $A$ is linear on a finite dimensional inner product space. How do I show that  $||Ax|| =||A^{*}x||$ for all $x$ implies that $A$ is normal?

Comment: What's the norm?

Comment: Sorry it is an inner product space

Comment: I think Schurs Theorem will work here.

Comment: .... since the theorem is easy to prove if the matrix representation is upper triangular

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the norm is induced by the inner product, then we have $$\| Ax\|^2= \langle Ax, Ax\rangle = \langle A^*Ax, x\rangle$$
Likewise $\| A^*x\|^2=\langle AA^*x, x\rangle$

Since $\| A^*x\|^2=\| Ax\|^2$ holds for any $x$, we have $AA^*=A^*A$

Comment: How is the last line $\| A^*x\|^2=\| Ax\|^2$ different than the hypothesis?

Comment: $\| A^*x\| = \| Ax\|$ <=> $\| A^*x\|^2=\| Ax\|^2$

Comment: A slight elaboration is in order: @chaohuang has shown that $\langle (A^*A - A A^*) x , x \rangle = 0$ for all $x$. Since $(A^*A - A A^*)$ is self-adjoint, this implies that $A^*A - A A^* = 0$. (This property is not true in general, eg, take a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$.)

Comment: got it thanks !